# Change characters with accents

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to replace the characters with accent by characters without accents but it does not work. Someone has an idea? thank you

```
function epurer_code(texte) {
    var pattern_accent = new Array("é", "è", "ê", "ë", "ç", "à", "â", "ä", "î", "ï", "ù", "û", "ü", "ô", "ó", "ö");
    var pattern_replace_accent = new Array("e", "e", "e", "e", "c", "a", "a", "a", "i", "i", "u", "u", "u", "o", "o", "o");
    texte.value = texte.value.preg_replace(pattern_accent, pattern_replace_accent, texte.value);
}

<TEXTAREA style="color:black;" name="Body" id="Body" value="" rows="6" cols="60" maxlength="160" onkeyup="supaccent(this);"></TEXTAREA>
```

Comment: What did you get `preg_replace` from?

Comment: I think your looking forfor str_replace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one method how to solve it. `textarea` content will be replaced dynamically, with every `keyup` event.

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('Body');

function clean() {
  var mapObj = {
    "é": 'e',
    "ó": 'o',
    "ç": 'c',
    "è": 'e',
    "ê": 'e',
    "ç": 'c'
    //and so on...      
  }
  elem.value = elem.value.replace(/[éèêëçàâäîïùûüôóö]/g, match => mapObj[match]);
}
```

```html
<TEXTAREA style="color:black;" name="Body" id="Body" value="" rows="6" cols="60" maxlength="160" onkeyup="clean()"></TEXTAREA>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just modified your code. Used `pattern_accent` array to form regular expression `pattern_exp`. In replace pattern match method, I'm getting the position of matched accent in `pattern_accent` array and returning the accent at same position in `pattern_replace_accent` array.

```js
function supaccent(texte) {
    var pattern_accent = new Array("é", "è", "ê", "ë", "ç", "à", "â", "ä", "î", "ï", "ù", "û", "ü", "ô", "ó", "ö");
    var pattern_replace_accent = new Array("e", "e", "e", "e", "c", "a", "a", "a", "i", "i", "u", "u", "u", "o", "o", "o");

    var pattern_exp = new RegExp('['+pattern_accent.join()+']', 'g')

    texte.value = texte.value.replace(pattern_exp, function(match){
        var index = pattern_accent.indexOf(match);
        return index>=0?pattern_replace_accent[index]:match;
    });
}
```

```html
<TEXTAREA style="color:black;" name="Body" id="Body" value="" rows="6" cols="60" maxlength="160" onkeyup="supaccent(this);"></TEXTAREA>
```